# iOS-CocoaAsyncudpSocket: mp3 data sending from client CocoaAsyncudpSocket but largest data not send

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying now to send an mp3 data to the server app. I am sending UIImage data as per the below code on the client side. But, the issue is, it is NOT sending this mp3 data to the server front end app.I send small mp3 (2kb) than send but large mp3(50mb) not send server how to solve this problem please help.

Code: https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

```
- (IBAction)send:(id)sender
{
NSString *host = addrField.text;

if ([host length] == 0)
{
    [self logError:@"Address required"];
    return;
}

int port = [portField.text intValue];
if (port <= 0 || port > 65535)
{
    [self logError:@"Valid port required"];
    return;
}


NSString *msg = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rr2" ofType:@"mp3"];


if ([msg length] == 0)
{
    [self logError:@"Message required"];
    return;
}



NSData* data =[[NSData alloc]init];
data= [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:msg];

udpSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self  delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

//omitted error checking

[udpSocket enableBroadcast:YES error:nil];
[udpSocket bindToPort:port error:nil];
[udpSocket joinMulticastGroup:host error:nil];
[udpSocket beginReceiving:nil];
[udpSocket sendData:data toHost:host port:port withTimeout:-1 tag:1];



//tag++;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

UDP protocol has a limit on the max data that can be send. In this library it is set to 65535 for IPv4. Check if your data is exceeding this limit. If not set the limit to max value like this: -

> [udpSocket setMaxReceiveIPv4BufferSize:maxValue];

Comment: max4ReceiveSize = 9216;
  max6ReceiveSize = 9216;

Comment: This is the default limit. You can increase it. How much is your song data summing up-to? If it is more i suggest use of TCP protocol.

Comment: I increase it. but not any effect

Comment: How much is the song data?

Comment: 30mb song and this song convert nsdata than after nsdata size is 6054586 byte.

Comment: Then obviously it will fail; as the max limit you can increase UDP buffer limit is 65535 bytes. You can use the _GCDAsyncSocket_ class from same library to implement it via TCP protocol. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25786005/gcdasyncsocket-server-receive-data-only-first-time/25800894#25800894) thread for basic idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62237/discussion-between-gandalf-and-gami-nilesh).

Comment: how to send tcp protocol.you see and project for TCP transfer mp3 file?please help mi.

Comment: Come to the chat window.

Comment: i send this file using strieaming any idea please say how ?